# feed class from list

Tags: python, list, class, linguistics

I am still new to python but using it for my linguistics research.

So I am doing some research into toponyms, and I got a list of input data from a topographic institution, which looks like the following:
Official_Name, tab, Dialect_Name, tab, Administrative_district, Topographic_district, Y_coordinates, X_coordinates, Longitude, Latitude.

So, I defined a class:

```
class MacroTop:
      def __init__(self, Official_Name, Dialect_Name, Adm_District, Topo_District, Y, X, Long, Lat):
          self.Official_Name = Official_Name
          self.Dialect_Name = Dialect_Name
          self.Adm_District = Adm_District
          self.Topo_District = Topo_District
          self.Y = Y
          self.X = X
          self.Long = Long
          self.Lat = Lat
```

So, with `open()`, I wanted to load my `.txt` file with the data I have to read it into the class using a loop but it did not work.

The result I want is to be able to access a feature of the class, say, Dialect_Name and be able to look through all the entries of that feature. I can do that just in the loop, but I wanted to define a class so I could be able to do more manipulation afterwards.

my loop:

```
with open("locLuxAll.txt", "r") as topo_list:
    lines = topo_list.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split('\t')
        print(line)
        print(line[0])  # This would access all the data that is characterized as Official_Name
```

I tried to make another loop:

```
for i in range(0-len(lines)):
        lines[i] = MacroTop(str(line[0]), str(line[1]), str(line[2]), str(line[3]), str(line[4]), str(line[5]), str(line[6]), str(line[7]))
```

But that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This line fails:

```
for i in range(0-len(lines)):
```

You're trying to loop through negative number I guess, so the output will be an empty list.

```
In [11]: [i for i  in range(-200)]
Out[11]: []
```

EDIT:
Your code seems unreadable to me, you have `for i in range(len(lines))` but in this `for` loop, you're iterating through `line` variable, where is it from? First of all I'd not write back to `lines` list as it comes from `readlines`. Create new list for that, and you dont need `i` variable, those lines will be kept in order anyway.

```
class_lines = []
for line in lines:
    class_lines.append(MacroTop(str(line[0]), str(line[1]), str(line[2]), str(line[3]), str(line[4]), str(line[5]), str(line[6]), str(line[7])))
```

Or even with list comprehension:

```
class_lines = [MacroTop(str(line[0]), str(line[1]), str(line[2]), str(line[3]), str(
    line[4]), str(line[5]), str(line[6]), str(line[7])) for line in lines]
```

Comment: Oh, I see the mistake there. Changed it to range(len(lines). But still, the output ist not what I wanted as the class is not being fed by the data. Any more ideas?

Comment: @MSam there's logic error in your initial code, but please check my updated answer if that helps

Comment: Mybe I should rectify my initial search, I think I did not express that well.

Comment: I have been provided with a file with Names and coordinates and so on as mentioned above, which I then converted to a .txt file. The thing is, there is plenty of data. There are actually a thousand lines in it with each line referring to one place. So by using print(lines), I get a list of all those instances, by referring to line (used that as I found it in most tutorials, later changed it to var_item though, to reduce conclusion) I can access the different variables. for example, if I use print(line[0]), I get ALL the instances of Official_Name, and so on.

Comment: So, I am looking for a way to feed all that data, the 8 variable items from all 1000 lines into my class to be able to access it, without having to type each line in separately. I tried your amended code actually before, but that did not work, which is the reason I thought I could iterate through the lines list (with i). Maybe I am doing something wrong with my class?